# jq reformatting decimals in scientific notation -- can this be avoided?

Tags: json, bash, decimal, jq, number-formatting

I found difference between json-data created by JavaScipt and via `jq` with bash (and other programming languages). With JavaScript I can create decimal numbers with up to six digits after the point, even when I use `float()`. But with `jq` its different, because adding a decimal value takes four digits after the decimal point only.

My problem is that I need decimal numbers to store in SQL, with up to six digits after the point.

Example:

```
$ JSON='{"decimal":0.00001}'
$ echo "$JSON" | jq .
{
  "decimal": 1e-05
}
```

My goal is to validate the decimal with this line ...

```
if [[ "$TMP_DECIMAL" =~ ^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]] ; then
```

Any tip / suggsestion ?

Comment: This doesn't look like a bash-vs-JavaScript question at all. This is `jq`'s own formatting, not anything done by bash -- if you called `jq` from Python or Java or C it would behave in precisely the same way.

Comment: Backing up, though: **What's the question, *exactly*?**. Do you want to stop `jq` from using scientific notation? Do you want to extend your regex in bash to accommodate scientific notation?

Comment: I just wantetd to point out the differnece when creating json-data. My problem is  with `bash` and `jq` only.

Comment: You right,I want to stop jq from using scientific notation

Comment: No, it is **not** with bash and jq only. If I have to do so to convince you, I'll write a Python program that starts `jq` without bash, and has the same problem.

Comment: Ahh! Well, good, then -- I'm glad I edited the title in a way that accords with what your intent actually is. That said, right now, the answer is "you can't". See https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1192

Comment: ...also https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1363, which is a larger feature request, but goes into why upstream is inclined to refuse this kind of change request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't change `jq`'s behavior -- at present date, [relevant feature requests](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1192) are still open -- but you *can* reformat your numbers after they've been retrieved. For example:

```
json='{"decimal":0.00001}'
decimal=$(jq '.decimal' <<<"$json")
decimal_f=$(awk -v decimal="$decimal" 'BEGIN { printf("%f\n", decimal) }' </dev/null)

echo "JQ emitted $decimal; reformatted as $decimal_f"
```

Comment: You on the right track, thx. But  I never worked with `awk` before. I just learn to understand all this.  Is it possible to make decimals with two, four and six digits after the point ? And can you explain why there is no `END` in your awk line (probably a noob questen).

Comment: Great Answer, what impact does `</dev/null` have in the command substitution btw? It could potentially work fine without it! @Charles Duffy!

Comment: @Inian, stops awk from trying to eat stdin, hanging if stdin is connected to a TTY, etc.

Comment: after some research I got almost the info i needed. Your code works well. thx for that. only one think I am missing... a description of `%f`

Comment: @suleiman, see `man printf`, or the relevant POSIX specification at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap05.html#tag_05 -- if you scroll down there you'll see the specification for `f` and `F`.

Comment: If you have _only_ BEGIN action(s) awk does not read its input, including stdin. See _its_ man page (info for GNU) or POSIX http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13 at subhead 'Special Patterns'. Although `awk '{printf "%f\n",$0)}' <<<"$decimal"` is shorter and does use input.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can reformat your `JSON` using perl module [JSON::PP](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/JSON/lib/JSON/backportPP.pm#allow_bignum).

```
perl -0777 -MJSON::PP -E '$s=<>; $j=JSON::PP->new->ascii->pretty->allow_nonref->allow_bignum;$p=$j->decode($s);say $j->encode($p)'
```

or nicer:

```
perl -0777 -MJSON::PP -E '
    $j=JSON::PP->new->ascii->pretty->allow_nonref->allow_bignum;
    $p=$j->decode(<>);
    say $j->encode($p)'
```

The crucial is the `allow_bignum`.

Example:

```
echo '{"decimal":0.00000001}' | perl ....
```

prints

```
{
   "decimal" : 0.00000001
}
```

but without the `allow_bignum` prints

```
{
   "decimal" : 1e-08
}
```

Ps: ... and also, is possible to validate the whole json using perl... :)

Answer (score 0):

[A commit made on Oct 21, 2019](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/commit/cf4b48c7ba30cb30e116b523cff036ea481459f6), ensures that jq will generally preserve the "external" format of numbers. There are some exceptions, e.g. superfluous leading 0s.

The following page gives details about installing an "unreleased" version of jq: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Installation