# JQ filter formatting

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I have a JSON file I'd like to filter by the ID field, and show the matching Body and Source fields.

Format of the JSON file to filter

```
[
{
   "timestamp" : 1638550971085,
   "id" : "54f",
   "body" : "Orange",
   "source" : "827261"
},
{
   "timestamp" : 1638550971096,
   "id" : "54f",
   "body" : "Apple",
   "source" : "137261"
},
{
   "timestamp" : 1638550971126,
   "id" : "5da",
   "body" : "Pear",
   "source" : "1da61"
}
]
```

In this example I would like to filter where id = 54f and show the Timestamp (Unixtime converted to local time), Body and Source fields that match, ideally as shown below.

```
[Timestamp]    Orange     827261
[Timestamp]    Apple      137261
```

I have tried this command, but it is showing extra body / source fields outside of the SQL filter. It also adds a line break between printing the body and source, and ideally I'd like this printed on one line (tab separated). I also don't know how to convert the timestamp to localtime string.

```
more file.json | jq '.[] | select(.Id=="54f").body, .source'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON input is **not** proper JSON as it has

- commas after the `.source` field but no following field
- no commas between the elements of the top-level array
- no quotes around the objects' field names

You'd need to address these issues first before proceeding. This is how it should look like:

```json
[
  {
    "timestamp": 1638550971085,
    "id": "54f",
    "body": "Orange",
    "source": "827261"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": 1638550971096,
    "id": "54f",
    "body": "Apple",
    "source": "137261"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": 1638550971126,
    "id": "5da",
    "body": "Pear",
    "source": "1da61"
  }
]
```

Then you can go with this

- `localtime` (available since jq 1.6) converts a timestamp of seconds (so, divide yours by 1000) since the Unix epoch into a so-called "broken down time" object (see the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)) which you can either process using `strftime` (see the [answer from David Conrad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73529922/2158479)), or parse yourself manually. With `.[:3] | .[1] += 1 | join("-")` I provided a rather primitive example for demonstration purposes which concatenates its first three items (year, month, day) with dashes in between, after incrementing the second item (as the month has a 0-based encoding) - for padding with zeroes check out one of the answers over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64957982/how-to-pad-numbers-with-jq)
- `@tsv` creates tabs between the columns

```bash
jq -r '
  .[]
  | select(.id == "54f")
  | [(.timestamp / 1000 | localtime | .[:3] | join("-")), .body, .source]
  | @tsv
' file.json
```

```
2021-12-3   Orange  827261
2021-12-3   Apple   137261
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IAflnD7pPa2)

Comment: The month in the "broken down time" goes from 0-11, not 1-12, so you are displaying the wrong month. There is an easy way to fix that *and* to display leading zeroes without any left pad code. Use `| localtime | strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`.

Comment: @DavidConrad Thank you for pointing out these issues. I have fixed the month issue and referenced your solution for the approach with `strftime`.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer states, your JSON is not correct. After fixing that, you can filter and extract the data as that answer suggests, but use the `strftime` function to format the dates properly:

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.id == "54f")
    | [(.timestamp / 1000 | localtime | strftime("%Y-%m-%d")), .body, .source]
    | @tsv' file.json
```

The use of `strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` is critical to both displaying the correct month and formatting the date with leading zeroes on single-digit months and days.

```
2021-12-03      Orange  827261
2021-12-03      Apple   137261
```