# How do I use jq to output a decimal low in linux

Tags: json, bash, formatting, jq, numeric

Given the following jq command and Json:  (Only jq command)

```
echo '{"foo": {"bar": 0.00000072}}' | jq 'map_values( . + {"bar": .bar|tostring} )'
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": "7.2e-07"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to format the output as:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": "0.00000072"
  }
}
```

OR

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": 0.00000072
  }
}
```

Comment: To my mind,this is not a duplicate of the linked-to question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956806/jq-reformatting-decimals-in-scientific-notation-can-this-be-avoided because here a numeric JSON string is deemed acceptable, whereas the other question is much more difficult (i.e, practically speaking, impossible) to solve using jq alone.

Comment: Hmm. I *could* see an ugly hack using jq alone to build an answer for the other on top of what you've got here (using `tojson` and a unique sigil as a string-search/replace token to generate raw output that happens to be valid JSON), but it's indeed more involved.

Comment: Not sure what you mean ... you'd have to write a new pretty-printer, which is quite a lot of work.  The need for user control over formatting is so great that I'm hopeful that it will happen sooner rather than very much later, so for now I'm inclined to wait ...

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your replies.  since it is definitive that with "jq" only it is not possible to do it, I recognize that in this question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956806/jq-reformatting-decimals-in-scientific-notation-can-this-be-avoided" is the cleanest option and the one that adapts to my need.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this generic function:

```
def to_decimal:
  def rpad(n): if (n > length) then . + ((n - length) * "0") else . end;
  def lpad(n): if (n > length) then ((n - length) * "0") + . else . end;
  tostring
  | . as $s
  | capture( "(?<sgn>[+-]?)(?<left>[0-9]*)(?<p>\\.?)(?<right>[0-9]*)(?<e>[Ee]?)(?<exp>[+-]?[0-9]+)" )
  | if .e == "" then $s
    else (.left|length) as $len
    | (.exp | tonumber) as $exp
    | if $exp < 0 then .sgn + "0." + (.left | lpad(1 - $exp - $len)) + .right
      else .sgn + (.left | rpad($exp - $len)) + "." + .right
      end
    end ;
```

Example:

```
"7.2e-07"|to_decimal
```

yields:

```
"0.00000072"
```

Comment: This would be a really great answer on the preexisting/canonical instance of this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956806/jq-reformatting-decimals-in-scientific-notation-can-this-be-avoided, now linked in flagging the current instance duplicative).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Wow! I didn’t realize I have magical powers (to reopen).

Comment: I'd *hope* you'd be a gold-badge in `jq` by now; I've learned most of what I know of the language from your answers.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I might lose it by chatting here, but let me say that coming from you, that's a real compliment!  I'll count it as a Platinum Badge :-)