# How to extract float values in number format instead of exponential values using jq?

Tags: precision, jq, number-formatting

Im extracting few fields from a list of jsons in a file using jq and one of the field contains a float value (eg.float 0.0000875) which when extracted through jq changed to '8.75e-05'. Is there a way we can extract these values without being converted to exponential form?

Comment: See - [jq reformatting decimals in scientific notation — can this be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42956806/5291015)

Answer (score 0):

The "master" version of jq now generally preserves the "external" number format, e.g.

```
$ jq -n '0.0000875'
0.0000875
```

The [relevant commit](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/commit/cf4b48c7ba30cb30e116b523cff036ea481459f6) date was Oct 21, 2019.

For some installation guidelines, see https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Installation

Comment: Tried doing the same with jq 1.6.

Wherever the value is '0.0000875' it is getting extracted as '8.75e-05' but if the non zero digit after the decimal is in 4th position im able to fetch the value as is (eg. 0.0009125). Can you please mention the version ? @peak

Comment: The version with the fix has not been officially released yet. You will either have to build from “master” or install a sufficiently updated binary as per the Installation page already mentioned.